# RabbitMQ Manual Retry

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

How can manual retry work in RabbitMQ after a message has been put onto dead letter queue?

Does RabbitMQ provide an user interface through which you can do this? I assume here that RabbitMQ console does not provide you this capability.

Comment: What option worked for you? I'm also looking for a similar solution. I would need to be able to resend any message from a queue. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

The Rabbit MQ management interface would let you do this crudely, you can go into the deadletter queue, 'get' the message then copy the content. Go to the queue you want to retry the message on and 'publish' it directly to that queue.

Alternatively, you can enable the shovel plugin which allows you to move messages from one queue to another. The RabbitMQ Management plugin directly contains instructions on how to do this.

Comment: First option cannot really be offered as a solution to customer. To try second option, I enabled Shovel plug-in but it seems to do this automatically. Requirement is that an administrator must be able to inspect a message and put it to back on the queue through an user interface. The queue that the message goes to should be automatically selected.

Comment: This is, essentially, custom functionality. Almost a workflow/user interaction kind of scenario. Maybe write up a little app for this? Wouldnt be too hard/take too much time.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a consumer / producer using a number of various client libraries. For python a popular library is pika (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pika).

The script can consume all the messages in a queue, then publish them to another queue.

Comment: Again I'm not looking at consuming and publishing messages to queue automatically. An administrator needs to manually inspect the message and manually trigger re-try.

Comment: You can manually inspect the message, and have the script consume/publish a single message at a time. Then run the script for each message you inspect.